# No known class method for selector 'setEnabled'

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to enable the UIPanGestureRecognizer when the user presses on a button so they can pan an object.

I got an error stating No known class method for selector 'setEnabled:'

code:

```
[UIPanGestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to send that method call to a specific gesture recognizer

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[gestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
```

What you were trying to do was send the `setEnabled:` message to the class `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, which is impossible.

Comment: For some reason this code is not enabling or disabling the pan. The only way I am able to enable or disable the pan is to uncheck the state of the gesture in storyboards. Any idea?

Comment: This code would only disable `gestureRecognizer`. To disable the one in the storyboard, make an `IBOutlet` in your class and connect it to the gesture recognizer in Interface Builder. You would then call `setEnabled:` on that gesture recognizer.